# NetworkCredentials exposes password in plain text

Tags: c#, .net

I'm about to create an authentication module in my C#/WPF application. To authenticate the user, I would like to use [`NetworkCredential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx) to store the credentials.

```
Credential = new NetworkCredential(credential.UserName, credential.Password);
```

Where the `credential.UserName` is a `string` and `credential.Password` is of the type `SecureString`. When debugging the application I can see the password in plain text as well as in secure string

[image]

Why is the password exposed as plain text? Isn't this a possible security threat?

Thanks for answering.

**EDIT:**

For the record, the `NetworkCredential` object shall be used on the WCF client, like this:

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = Credentials
```

Comment: Isn't which a possible security threat? That you can inspect it at run-time if you're debugging? You can do most things during run-time with a debugger attached.

Comment: @JayMee I think the point being that since `NetworkCredential` takes a `SecureString` in the constructor, it ought to not immediately then expose it as a plain text property on itself, and to anyone else that's looking.  "Thanks for passing me this secure information.  Hey everyone, look at this!"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. So what should we expect to see as the value of `SecureString`? An encrypted string? I'm not the best person to answer this (which is why I'm commenting instead), I'm genuinely curious what the threats may be.

Comment: @JayMee No I'm saying the `NetworkCredential` shouldn't take a `SecureString`, get it's value and expose it as a normal `String`.  What's the point in passing it a `SecureString` if it's going to do that with it?  Me too - I'm just (hopefully!) clarifying the question a bit...

Comment: @JayMee The question is, why is there both a `SecureString SecurePassword` and `string Password`. `SecurePassword` doesn't seem very secure if you can get its actual value from `Password`. It is counter-intuitive.

Comment: @sab669 Secure *how*? What kind of security did you lose by having an extra property that converts the secure string to a normal string? How is it different from doing the same thing with a method call? The contents of the secure string have *never* been hidden from *your* application.

Comment: @sab669 Properties are not required to be backed exactly by fields. As the accepted answer shows, the password string is *not* stored in the object.

Comment: @sab669 If that's how you deal with things, you have grave security issues indeed. The whole point of `SecureString` is to protect against *outside* threats, not *your own application*. What would be the point of that? No matter the security of `NetworkCredentials` or anything else, I could always simply snatch the password when the user enters it, no need to muck around hacking `SecureString`.

Comment: Well I clearly have some sort of fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on here. Let's take a hypothetical situation where we pass this `NetworkCredential` object over a network. What is there to stop someone sitting there with a packet sniffer of some sort from looking at this object and viewing its public `Password` property? I suppose the argument then falls to "Why didn't you secure the connection?" but let's ignore that and assume you're under the assumption that you don't need it since `SecureString` sounds safe for transmission.

Comment: @sab669, because the Password property is code and not data. A packet sniffer examines data, and does not execute code; indeed there is no Password property/code in the packet for the sniffer to execute, just data, and the Password property is not in the packet data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `NetworkCredential` class internally [*always* stores the password](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/NetworkCredential.cs,125) as a `SecureString`:

```
 public string Password {
        get {
            ExceptionHelper.UnmanagedPermission.Demand();
            return InternalGetPassword();
        }
        set {
            m_password = UnsafeNclNativeMethods.SecureStringHelper.CreateSecureString(value);
        }
    }
```

When someone needs to retrieve the password as plain text (which at some point will be needed, either from this class or somewhere further down the chain), it [retrieves it from the secure string](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/NetworkCredential.cs,192):

```
    internal string InternalGetPassword() {
        string decryptedString = UnsafeNclNativeMethods.SecureStringHelper.CreateString(m_password);
        return decryptedString;
    }
```

When using the debugger, it shows the properties, so the value is retrieved from the `SecureString`

Answer (score 2):

`SecureString` has nothing to do with encryption! (a gross oversimplification -  it's *possible* it's also encrypted, but that's not all that important here; if you create a `SecureString` from a normal `string`, you've already negated plenty of gain of `SecureString` - short-term)

It's simply a string that can be deterministically deallocated. This is important for security reasons, since .NET strings may be very long lived (for interned strings, the whole life of the application).

`NetworkCredential` is not used for *storing* credentials - it's just a simple wagon to get them where they are going - a common API, basically.

Comment: But why have a class that takes a `SecureString` as a constructor parameter ("Hey you can trust me with this") only if it then exposes it as a normal `String`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Why wouldn't it? You have the `SecureString` property to get the secure string. Most APIs don't give you any way to *use* a `SecureString`. It's an opt-in feature, really. The `string` is created on demand, when you query the `Password` *property*.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that `SecureString` has nothing to do with encryption, but why does the `NetworkCredential` expose my password as plain text? Wouldn't this store the password as plain text in memory?

Comment: Because as soon as you've passed your supposedly `SecureString` to this class, it's no longer given the same security?

Comment: @JamesThorpe `Password` is a *property*. The string is only created if you *explicitly ask for it* - of course, the debugger tends to query all the properties of a watched object. The string doesn't exist in memory until you ask for that conversion.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen It simply gives you a way to read the password as string. If you *don't* do that, and keep using the `SecureString` property, there's no "breach". The `Password` property is there simply for the APIs that don't support `SecureString`.

Comment: @Luaan Yes - just realised that and went looking for the relevant code :)

Comment: It's about as good as rot13. It protects a bit against the casual observer only.  I see no secure way to create a script that sets passwords without revealing to anyone who see those codes from being able to extract the password from it. Ideally there would be a public key based algorithm to set a password checker that doesn't reveal the password itself in the process.